# How to remove adjacent duplicates in a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I've been looking for this answer for a while.
I've found numbers of solutions for removing duplicates using a HashSet or LinkedHashSet but they all remove all duplicates, I'm looking for only the adjacent ones. "
Say a string is "ABBCDAABBBBBBBBOR" 
The required result should be "ABCDABOR" and not "ABCDOR".
Could this be achived in O(n) ? Thanks.

Comment: I really would like to see Java-8 + regex examples...

Comment: @Jay — As requested, a very straightforward regex example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76891701/1108305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
char previous = chars[0];
sb.append(chars[0]);
for(int i = 1 ; i < chars.length ; i++) {
    if(chars[i] != previous) {
        sb.append(chars[i]);
        previous = chars[i];
    }
}
String res = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

O(n) time solution :

```
public String removeAdjacentDuplicates(String s) {
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char previous = s.charAt(0);
    resultBuilder.append(previous);
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char current = s.charAt(i);
        if (previous != current) {
            resultBuilder.append(current);
            previous = current;
        }
    }
    return resultBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: O(n) time, yes, but O(n) space also.  StringBuilder resultBuilder's size is directly related to the size of String s.
The only practical way I see to make it O(1) space is if the deduplicated string was never stored; you'd have to output it while processing.  As long as the method must return a separate deduplicated string then you will need additional storage that is directly related to the size of the input string..
However, if the input were a char array then you could reuse the passed array, but with all the swaps you'd go O(n^2) for time.
Space vs time, as always.

Comment: Good point, but space used for storing result is almost always ignored in space complexity analysis.

Comment: This method is exactly the kind of thing I would have written.  I assumed the OP meant time when I saw the question and didn't even think of space until I saw it here.  I assume the question comes from a student and thought we should provide the most accurate answer possible.  The space used by this algorithm increases linearly with the number of characters in the input string, so O(n).  O(1) would mean that the space used by the algorithm was constant; it would consume the same amount of space regardless of the length of the input string.

Comment: I absolutely agree. Edited original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting to work with streams so bear with me...

```
public static String removeAdjacentDuplicates(String input) {
    if (input.length() <= 1) {
        return input;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(input.charAt(0));

    IntStream.range(1, input.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(i - 1) ? input.charAt(i) : "")
        .forEach(sb::append);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

or if this more your style instead of the StringBuilder:

```
return input.charAt(0) + String.join("", 
    IntStream.range(1, input.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(i - 1) ?
            String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)) : "")
        .toArray(size -> new String[size]));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete solution using Java.

```
public class Occurence2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String a = "ABBCDAABBBBBBBBOR"; //ABCDABOR
        String a = "GiiinnnniiiiiGinnnaPrrooottijayyyi";//GiniGinaProtijayi
        fix(a);
    }// amin

    private static void fix(String a) {
        StringBuffer sbr = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char ch = a.charAt(i);
            if (sbr.length() == 0) {
                sbr.append(ch);
            }
            if (ch == sbr.charAt(sbr.length() - 1)) {
                i++;
            } else {
                sbr.append(ch);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sbr);
    }// fiix
}
```

If you don't want to use StringBuffer, then you can simply use an empty string.

```
public class Test6 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "GiiinnnniiiiiGinnnaPrrooottijayyyi";
    fix(a);
    }

private static void fix(String a) {
      String res = "";
    int i = 0 ;
     while(i < a.length()) {
         char ch = a.charAt(i);
         if(res.length() == 0 ) {res += ch ;}
         if(ch == res.charAt(res.length() -1)) {i++ ;}
         if(ch != res.charAt(res.length() -1)) {res += ch ;}
     }//while
      System.out.println(res);
}//fix

}
```

The solution in Python:

```
a = "GiniiiiGinaaaPrrrottiijayi"

reslist =[]
for ch in a:
     if(len(reslist) == 0 or ch != reslist[-1]):reslist.append(ch)

print(reslist)
print(''.join(reslist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex-based solution.  I can't promise it's O(n), since the Java regex implementation doesn't guarantee any particular time complexity.

```java
string.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

This matches any character as a capturing group, followed by one or more occurrences of that capturing group (i.e. one ore more occurrences of that character).  It replaces that sequence of characters by the result of that capturing group (i.e. by just the single character).