# Remove adjacent duplicates from a String

Tags: java, string, time, time-complexity

I need to write a function that receives a String and removes adjacent duplicates.

Example:

Input -> "aabbaabbcccaaa"

Output -> "ababca"

I tried to solve it as follows:

```
public String remdups(String input) {
    String response = "";
    char temp;
    int i, length = input.length();

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        temp = input.charAt(i);
        response += temp;

        while(i < length && input.charAt(i) == temp) i++;
    }
    return response;
}
```

But it seems that time complexity is not as expected, how could I improve perfomance or what would be a better approach?
I know it's a really simple problem, but I can't find a way to improve or another way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by time complexity is not as expected? It is only going through the string once. The only improvement you could do is to get the characters as an array from the string rather than use `charAt()` and append them to a `StringBuilder` rather than create a new String with `+=`.

Comment: ^ This is the singular best way to optimize repeated appends with Strings - StringBuilder keeps a buffer of characters rather than repeatedly creating a new String for each append.

Comment: I don't know, this problem showed up for me at https://www.testdome.com and when I've tried that solution, it said that it was taking too long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove adjacent duplicates in a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917393/how-to-remove-adjacent-duplicates-in-a-string-in-java) and other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me your code looks already good from a complexity point of view. It is only going through the String once. The optimisations you could do are on the response `String` by using a `StringBuilder`, and maybe simplifying the loop a bit just for readability (no need for 2 nested loops, and incrementing the `i` counter from 2 places could introduce mistakes).

```
public String remdups(String input) {
  StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(input.length());
  char temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
     char next = input.charAt(i);
     if (temp != next) {
       temp = next;
       response.append(temp);
     }
  }

  return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: By default, a new `StringBuilder` will be created with a capacity of 16. Since this is for an online code test, it's possible they're using a mix of small and large inputs to evaluate each submission. If repeated `.append()` calls are made that exceed the capacity, there will be a cost to grow the internal buffer. To prevent this, you could initialize the `StringBuilder` with a specific capacity (such as `input.length()`) or just pass the string itself, like this: `new StringBuilder(input)` (which will set capacity to `input.length() + 16`).

Comment: I ran out of room in the above comment, but here's a link for [StringBuilder's default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder()) which states: _"Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity of 16 characters."_

Comment: Nice observation. Updated the answer. `input.length()` should be enough because the string cannot grow.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try something with regex? Like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aabbaabbcccaaa";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+","$1"));
}
```

Output:

```
ababca
```

**Edit:**
For future reference, this approach turns out to be abysmally slow. I benchmarked it with JMH and it’s approximately 4x slower than the non-regex solution for short strings, and only gets worse for longer (~10k character) strings.

Comment: Your code solves the problem, but using Regular Expressions can be very expensive. the most correct answer is provided by @jbx that is guaranteed linear time.